# How do I see the aggregates of my published "news.reads" actions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, aggregation

I have a Facebook application that wants to publish document reads to a user's OpenGraph.

Since `read` is a reserved, built-in action, my `object`s have to have the type `article`. The publishing of reads to the user's graph works fine and the last read is also shown on the user's timeline.

[image: See the successful display of the read 'Third Magazine' here]

Additionally, I have set up some aggregators that would show the last 5 reads, the most popular authors etc. The problem is that I can not find those aggregators anywhere in my timeline/profile or in the App section of my user.

[image: See the set up objects, actions and aggregators here]

**Is it not possible to control/show the aggregators for built-in actions and objects?**
I have a feeling it should be, since I can set them up and (for example) Spotifiy also uses the built-in `music.song` objects, as shown below - this is basically, what I also want.

[image: Aggregation, that I am looking for]

All I am seeing on my app's timeline section, though, is this:

[image: Aggregation, that I am getting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the perfect answer to the actual question but I was able to solve the problem nevertheless. In case someone else is in the same spot, you might profit from my learnings:

The application I'm building wants to push `read` actions to a user's OpenGraph. My aggregation problem was that my reads from the built-in `news.reads` action did not get aggregated. To this day, I do not know why not.

Instead, I managed to create my own `read` action. It is not connected to the built-in one and exists in my own namespace.
This action can now be connected to my own objects as well and is not bound to the `article` object – as is the built-in one.

Having my own actions and objects, it was a breeze to follow the [instructions for aggregations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-units/) and create as many aggregations as I like. They also actually show up in my test users' profiles. Yeah.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not in control of when facebook displays your aggregations as you have defined them in your open graph settings, since facebook uses the so called 'GraphRank' to determine whether to show your aggregation or not. The calculation goes like this:

> GraphRank = affinity * weight * interactions * time

- affinity (score): this is the relationship between the viewing user and the creator of the action.
- weight: if two users interact frequently with each other, the respective actions in the open graph are rated higher than for users who do not have the same interest and are not in close contact on Facebook.
- interactions: how often does the user interact with the application and how do friends react to the activities in the social channels (if nobody clicks on the published actions it's bad for the GraphRank).
- time: if an app is used irregularly or only once, actions will receive less attention in the long run and will be presented less prominently on the timeline.

See this article: http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/12/27/edgerank-and-graph-rank-defined/

Comment: Hey Lego, thanks for your answer and the link. It seems, though, as if GraphRank only applies to what users see in their news feed, not on the dedicated app page. The GraphRank seems to decide what and how many OpenGraph actions a user sees from his friends in his feed. I should be able to see all my OpenGraph actions in a dedicated place, though, optionally aggregated as specified by the developer and/or Facebook.

Comment: Actually yes, but if I look into a Spotify app page of a friend of mine who uses Spotify extensively, I can see detailed aggregations as well as some of the sort "USER_NAME listened to 51 songs." So to me it seems as if Facebook decides for itself when to show an aggregation as defined in the app settings. Anyway I understand your confusion and would also be happy to read a answer to your question written by someone from the FB dev support team. @Igy?

Comment: I'm sure Facebook decides to some extent itself, what to show in the aggregations. But the aggregation itself is created by the app developer. So the dev can decide, what data to aggregate how.
I agree that some autoritative answer would go a long way in helping here :-)